# cross-chain atomic swaps for integration between enterprise blockchain solutions (quorum, hyperledger, R3 corda)

Tags: quorum, swaps, cross-chain

Understand that cross-chain atomic swaps is for asset transfer between different cryptos.

In a world where there are different enterprise blockchains, cross-chain atomic swaps as a concept/foundation for integration between enterprise blockchain solutions (quorum, hyperledger, R3 corda) is the way forward.

Has anyone integrated enterprise ethereum (quorum) with hyperledger and/or R3 corda via cross-chain atomic swaps?

Answer (score 1):

There is ongoing work regarding it here:

https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridge

It will eventually evolve to Polkadot network.

Comment: thanks. does interledger counts as well?

Comment: The project is still in its infancy, so probably not today, but tomorrow yes.

Answer (score 1):

Ion Protocol developed by Clearmatics has implemented Cross-chain atomic swaps. See below link:

https://github.com/clearmatics/ion

As part of Stage 1, they have successfully implemented an atomic swap of ERC-223 tokens across two Ethereum chains. They plan to extend this to other Turing complete Blockchain platforms as part of Stage 2. See their blog post on Medium here:

https://medium.com/clearmatics/ion-stage-2-toward-a-general-interoperability-protocol-part-1-d12b9d7316d3